# Вложенные прямоугольники python

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы

Нужна помощь в решении задачи:

Заполните прямоугольный массив вложенными прямоугольниками. Клетки, находящиеся на краях прямоугольника, заполняются числом 0, соседние с ними клетки заполняются числом 1, соседние с ними — числом 2 и т.д.

```
Пример для n=6m=9
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 0
0 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: И что, Вы не можете расстояние до края посчитать? Или какая-то другая проблема? Задайте вопрос именно о ней с приведением своего кода.

Comment: Нужно удалять такие вопросы. Ибо есть для нормального оформления вопроса [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @And Если вопрос можно исправить, нажав "править" под вопросом, то стоит вопросы не удалять, а закрывать, указав автору на недочёты. Дайте участнику шанс исправить вопрос, что ж сразу удалять-то?

Comment: @AK, правят единицы, в основном уходят на другой ресурс, а вопрос так и валяется без надобности. Надо, задаст новый, но уже умнее будет в следующий раз. А создавать свалку, не есть хорошо.

Comment: @And Ну хорошо, правят единицы, но вы к конкретному человеку обращаетесь. Получается как в том анекдоте "ну тогда пусть и за изнасилование судят, инструмент-то есть", когда человека наказывают не за уже совершённый поступок, а за саму возможность совершить нарушение. Вы заранее настраиваете себя на то, что этого человека уже в утиль, а его -- на то, что тут к новичкам такое отношение и этим своим действием вы и тех немногих, кто исправляется устремляете к нулю.

Comment: @AK, нашли, что сравнивать. Вам надо в судьи мистер!

Comment: @And Печально, что вы не хотите понять и отшучиватесь.

Comment: @And вопрос, к слову, в целом хороший. Я бы сказал, что кому-то даже может быть интересен.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В задаче вы спрашиваете про прямоугольный массив. Я сделал список списков, не знаю в таком ли формате нужен ответ, в любом случае логика будет похожая.

Каждое число - это минимальное значение из 4х:

- Текущего номера столбца (от 0 до m - 1)
- Текущего номера строки (от 0 до n - 1)
- Текущего номера столбца, если считать с правого края (m - обычный номер столбца - 1)
- Текущего номера столбца, если считать снизу (n - обычный номер строки - 1)

Минимальное значение можно найти с помощью стандартной функции `min`, а матрицу создать с помощью двойного спискового включения (можно и с помощью двух списков for, но так будет длиннее).

```py
n, m = 6, 9

matrix = [[min(x, y, m - x - 1, n - y - 1) for x in  range(m)] for y in range(n)]


for line in matrix:
    print(line)
```