# Задача крест Python

Tags: python, массивы

Заполните квадратный массив целыми числами по образцу. В углах записан число 0, 
в соседних с ними с углами клетках записано число 1, в соседних с ними клетках записано число 2 и т.д. 
Клетки считаются соседними, если у них есть общая сторона или вершина.

```
Пример для n=8
0 1 2 3 3 2 1 0 
1 1 2 3 3 2 1 1 
2 2 2 3 3 2 2 2 
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
2 2 2 3 3 2 2 2 
1 1 2 3 3 2 1 1 
0 1 2 3 3 2 1 0
```

Мое решение:

```
n = 8
a = []
for i in range(n):
a.append([])
for j in range(n):
    # top & left
    if j < n//2 and i < n//2:
        x = max(i, j)
    # top & right
    elif j >= n//2 and i < n//2:
        x = max(i, n-j-1)
    # down & left
    elif i >= (n//2) and j < n//2:
        x = max(n-i-1,j)
    # down & right
    else: x = max(n-i-1,n-j-1)
    a[i].append(x)
for k in a:
    print(*k)
```

Тоже самое но с генератором

```
N = 8
mtrx = [[max(i,j) if j < n//2 and i < n//2 
         else max(i, n-j-1) if j >= n//2 and i < n//2 
         else max(n-i-1,j) if i >= (n//2) and j < n//2 
         else max(n-i-1,n-j-1) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
for b in mtrx:
    print(*b)
```

Хотелось бы посмотреть на более изящные способы решения

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Задача похожа на вашу прошлую, только теперь проще использовать расстояние от центральных линий, а не от углов

```
 mtrx = [[(n - 1 - min(abs(n - 1 - 2 * i), abs(n - 1 - 2 * j))) // 2 
      for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 2):

По аналогии с этим [решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1045121/325224):

```
from pprint import pprint

n = 8    
mtrx = [[max(min(i, n - 1 - i), min(j, n - 1 - j)) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]

pprint(mtrx)
```

Для печати матрицы удобно использовать модуль `pprint`.

Answer (score 0):

Есть парочка отличных от других вариантов.
Первый вариант:

```py
n = 9
m = [[0] * n for x in range(n)]

half = n // 2 + n % 2
for i in range(half):
    for j in range(half):
        a = max(i, j)
        m[i][j] = a
        m[-i-1][j] = a 
        m[-i-1][-j-1] = a 
        m[i][-j-1] = a 
        
for k in m:
    print(*k)
```

Второй вариант:

```py
n = 9
half = n // 2
mat = [[max(x, y) for x in range(half)] for y in range(half)]
for m in mat:
    m.extend(m[::-1])
    if n % 2 == 1:
        m.insert(half, half)
mat.extend(mat[::-1])
if n % 2 == 1:
    mat.insert(half, [half] * w)

for k in mat:
    print(*k)
```