# Как сгенерировать такую матрицу?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Значения от 0 до 1

В итоге должен получиться такой результат:

```
1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0

1.0    0.5    0.5    0.5    1.0

1.0    0.5    0.0    0.5    1.0

1.0    0.5    0.5    0.5    1.0

1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
```

Будет проще, если представить в виде цвета

1 - абсолютно белый

0 - абсолютно черный

В таком случае стоит задача генерировать некий квадратный градиент, [вот такой](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz4oq.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Язык не важен, мне бы хотя бы понять алгоритм, буду благодарен за любую помощь)

Comment: Значение в поле есть линейная функция максимального из отклонений от центра матрицы.

Comment: Да просто смотрите, полдиагонали - это сколько по длине, делите на это число 1, получаете шаг. Получится примерно оно...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Т.к. матрица симметричная, то достаточно заполнить только её четверть, а потом отзеркалить по горизонтали и по вертикали.

```
max_value = 1.0
min_value = 0.0
steps = 3

# заготовка для четверти матрицы
quadrant = [[None]*steps for _ in range(steps)]

for start in range(steps):
    value = max_value - ((max_value - min_value) / (steps - 1) * start)
    for pos in range(start, steps):
        # заполняем вертикальный ряд вниз и горизонтальный вправо 
        # от стартовой (текущей) позиции
        quadrant[start][pos] = quadrant[pos][start] = value

# зеркалим по вертикали
matrix = quadrant + quadrant[::-1][1:]
# и по горизонтали
matrix = [row + row[::-1][1:] for row in matrix]

# вуаля :)
print("\n".join("  ".join([f"{elem:.3f}" for elem in row]) for row in matrix))
```

Получаем:

```
1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000
1.000  0.500  0.500  0.500  1.000
1.000  0.500  0.000  0.500  1.000
1.000  0.500  0.500  0.500  1.000
1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000
```

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Так здесь нечётное число и есть. Если нужно чётное, то при зеркалировании просто не надо отрезать первые элементы (убрать `[1:]`). Если матрица не квадратная, то тогда `value` надо рассчитывать отдельно для горизонтали и вертикали. Ну, и при желании, можно всё это объединить в универсальный алгоритм.

Comment: Вообще, можно было даже заполнить 1/8 часть (треугольник в четверти), а потом и его отзеркалить по диагонали. Но это только усложнит код.

Answer (score 2):

Делал [подобное ранее.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1196849/281034)

Этот вариант для квадратной матрицы:

```py
def make_matrix(n):
    m = [[0] * n for _ in range(n)]
    half = n // 2 + n % 2
    for i in range(half):
        for j in range(half):
            a = 1 - min(i, j) / (half - 1)
            m[i][j] = a
            m[-i-1][j] = a
            m[-i-1][-j-1] = a
            m[i][-j-1] = a
    return m

x = make_matrix(5)

for row in x:
    print(*[f"{i:.2f}" for i in row])

'''
1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00
1.00 0.50 0.50 0.50 1.00
1.00 0.50 0.00 0.50 1.00
1.00 0.50 0.50 0.50 1.00
1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00
'''
```

еще вариант, сначала создается центральная матрица с нулями, а затем она расширяется по  сторонам с определенным шагом:

```py
def make_matrix(n):
    half = n // 2 + n % 2
    if n % 2:
        m = [[0]]
    else:
        m = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
    v = 0
    step = 1 / (half - 1)
    for x in range(1, half):
        v += step
        for i in m:
            i.insert(0, v)
            i.append(v)
        sz = len(m[0])
        m.insert(0, [v] * sz)   
        m.append([v] * sz)  
    return m
```